# Hyperplanes in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ containing conjugacy classes of matrices

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory, linear-groups

Let $SL_2(K)$ be the special linear group of rank 2 over a field $K$, as an affine group scheme cut out by the equation $ad - bc = 1$ in $\mathbb{A}^4_K$.

Let $H$ be an arbitrary, homogeneous, hyperplane, which contains the identity $I$ of $SL_2(K)$ as a point. For example, take $H: 2c - d + a = 0$. (I am particularly interested in this hyperplane).

Is it possible for $H$ to contain an entire conjugacy class besides that of the identity?

Comment: The element -I is central, so...

Comment: To whomever person who looks at this question at the future, I didn't find any interesting abstract approach but observed how the polynomial I was interested in transforms under conjugation, and verified that if I start with an $SL_2(K)$ matrix different from $\pm I$, then there is always a conjugation which sends a point on the hyperplane to a point not on the hyperplane.

Comment: Write an answer with the details!